# Using an array of wildcards in a Powershell WHERE clause

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make the following PowerShell script more generic.  I want to pass in an array of excludes rather than a fixed list.  I can't figure out how to do this except my partial solution below:

ORIGINAL

This gets all the files in a path except a list of wildcard files or folders:

```
        Get-ChildItem -Path  "$sitePath" -Recurse | `
        where {!$_.PSIsContainer } | `
        Select -ExpandProperty FullName | `
            Where {$_ -notlike "$sitePath\Custom\*"} | `
            Where {$_ -notlike "$sitePath\Download\*"} | `
            Where {$_ -notlike "$sitePath\Temp\*"} | `
            Where {$_ -notlike "$sitePath\Portal\*"} | `
            Where {$_ -notlike "$sitePath\web.config*"} | `            
            SELECT $_
```

PARTIAL SOLUTION

This is the best I've come up with.  It allows me to create an array of wildcards called $excludeList, but is limited and is slightly slower:

```
        $excludeList = @("$sitePath\Custom\*",
                "$sitePath\Download\*",
                "$sitePath\Portal\*",
                "$sitePath\web.config*")

        Get-ChildItem -Path  "$sitePath" -Recurse | `
        where {!$_.PSIsContainer } | `
        Select -ExpandProperty FullName | `
            Where {$_ -notlike $excludeList[0]} | `
            Where {$_ -notlike $excludeList[1]} | `
            Where {$_ -notlike $excludeList[2]} | `
            Where {$_ -notlike $excludeList[3]} | `
            Where {$_ -notlike $excludeList[4]} | `
            Where {$_ -notlike $excludeList[5]} | `
            Where {$_ -notlike $excludeList[6]} | `
            Where {$_ -notlike $excludeList[7]} | `
            Where {$_ -notlike $excludeList[8]} | `
            Where {$_ -notlike $excludeList[9]} | `
            Where {$_ -notlike $excludeList[10]} | `
            SELECT $_
```

Is there a better way to pass an array in to the where clause?  All the solutions I've found only allow non-wildcard matches.

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to iterate over the items in the exclude list, and only include a path if it does not match any of the exclusions:

```powershell
$excludeList = @("$sitePath\Custom\*",
                 "$sitePath\Download\*",
                 "$sitePath\Portal\*",
                 "$sitePath\web.config*")

Get-ChildItem -Path "$sitePath" -Recurse |
  where { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
  select -ExpandProperty FullName |
  where { $path = $_; -not @($excludeList | ? { $path -like $_ }) }
```

If all of your excluded items follow the same pattern, you can also simplify the exclude list by moving the common pattern to the like call:

```powershell
$excludeList = @('Custom','Download','Portal','web.config')

Get-ChildItem -Path "$sitePath" -Recurse |
  where { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
  select -ExpandProperty FullName |
  where { $path = $_; -not @($excludeList | ? { $path -like "$sitePath\$_*" }) }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to go with a regex instead, you can simplify this a lot:

```
$excludeList = [regex]::Escape("$sitePath\Custom\"), 
               [regex]::Escape("$sitePath\Download\"),
               [regex]::Escape("$sitePath\Temp\") -join "|"
Get-ChildItem $sitePath -Recurse | `
    where {!$_.PSIsContainer } | `
    Select -ExpandProperty FullName | `
        Where {$_ -notmatch $excludeList}
```

Not sure why you have the trailing `Select $_`, it is unnecessary AFAICT.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I still get files with the paths in the exclude list.

Comment: Try again, the regex escape was escaping the or `|` character.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `-contains` and `-notcontains` operators if you are trying to compare against an array.

```
$array = "name1","name2","name3"

#This will return false
$array -contains "name"

#this will return true
$array -notcontains "name"
```

Comment: This only works with non-wildcard items in the array.  I need the array to have wildcard paths in it.